# teradata SQL convert real to timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata

I can't understand how to convert this type of real - `42389.520752314813` to timestamp.

I got this data from one source, but I need to convert it to normal timestamp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have received wrong input data.

this type of timestamp is only occurring when Destination tool is excel and which has CELL as "Number" type, and during Copy-Paste of timestamp, destination field has Calculated it as ***Mathematical*** function. Please re-verify your source. I am sure about this mathematical calculation. please check the below sample of such data. `So practically you cannot perform its reverse operation.`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to do without knowing what timestamp should be returned.

If the date is sourced from a SQL Server it might be '2016-01-22 12:29:53':

```
cast( date '1900-01-01' + myCol as timestamp(3)) 
+ (cast(86400 * (myCol mod 1) as dec(12,6)) * interval '00:00:01.000000' hour to second)
```

If it's from Excel it's two days earlier and you must start at '1899-12-30'

Comment: thank you! yes, it's from excel. just needed to change cells data type to 'date'